# mySQL select row per month and divide by total

Tags: mysql, percentage

I have a table that looks like this

```
May 2015    Red Reports            74
May 2015    Resolved               27
June 2015   Red                    17
June 2015   Resolved               48
June 2015   Blue                    1
```

How could I query such a table such that I maybe get the months grouped and the rows containing "resolved" divided by the total for that month in the subsequent row? And this subsequent row would be in the format of showing the 
actual division in parentheses and the percent right after?

For example, using the previous data one would obtain two columns. The first would be month and the second would be what I'm asking for:

```
May 2015    (27/101) 27%
June 2015   (48/66) 73%
```

Comment: is that really how you save dates?

Comment: Do your figures add up in the example? Should it be (27/101) & (48/66)?

Comment: Drew.. the date is saved in date format. The column I am displaying is the way I have formatted it in the first query. The query I'm asking for here will be used with my original being the subquery. So the first column is just titled "date" for simplicity. And I would like to use that.

Comment: You can cast and concat all you want. That is the job of the front-end. I would not turn a highly performant db engine into a report engine

Comment: I understand. I respect your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a sub-query to grab the resolved value for the month and then uses `SUM()` to get the total.

```
SELECT month, ((
  SELECT value
  FROM `test` t2
  WHERE t2.month = t1.month
    AND t2.name = 'resolved'
) / SUM(value)) AS 'percentage'
FROM `test` t1
GROUP BY month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries to get total and resolved, and concat them:

```
select total.y, total.m, concat('(', coalesce(resolved.n, 0), '/', total.n, ')') r
from (
  select year(d) y, month(d) m, sum(n) n 
  from t 
  group by year(d), month(d) ) total
left join (
  select year(d) y, month(d) m, sum(n) n 
  from t 
  where s = 'Resolved' 
  group by year(d), month(d) ) resolved on total.y = resolved.y and total.m = resolved.m;
```